# Creating line feature from two points that doesn't intersect with land / polygon feature using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, points-to-line, wildlife-ecology

I have some marine fish species data that is mark-recapture data i.e. coordinates for a fish tagged with a plastic ID tag and coordinates for the same fish recaptured at a later date (identified using the tag). I have ~300 recaptured fish in my dataset.

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

To show how far the fish has travelled, I have mapped the coordinates as line features using straight line distance.
As some of these lines cross land as straight lines / as the crow flies, I was wondering if there is a way to create the line features in a way that doesn't intersect with land polygons (I might even create a buffer around the coastline as well).
These fish can't walk / survive out of the water, so it's better if the lines showing distance travelled are actually in the ocean!

Comment: Do you have access to the Spatial Analyst extension?

Comment: You need to be using the [Cost Path](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/creating-the-least-cost-path.htm) tool to create the route the fish would take around a headland.

Comment: You can do this in vector space, but it will require effort (and a lot of trial and error). It's also unlikely that the fish took the exact fastest path, so you'd be introducing error to your analysis.